# Elementary geometry: perimeter of a polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a circle of centre $O$, $\mathscr{P}:= [a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ and $\mathscr{Q}:= [b_1, \ldots, b_m]$ two convex polygons, inscribed in $\mathscr{C}$ such that:

1. $O$ is inside $\mathscr{P}$ and $\mathscr{Q}$.
2. The shortest side of $\mathscr{P}$ is bigger than the longest side of $\mathscr{Q}$.

Then the perimeter de $\mathscr{P}$ is smaller than the perimeter de $\mathscr{Q}$.
[image]
I have a proof using trigonometry and a convex (or concave) inequality.
However I would be interested in a proof at middle school level, not using the notion of function. Any idea?

Comment: @achillehui, yes, thank you.

Comment: You don't need concave/convex inequality.  Trigonometry and the fact $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ is decreasing over $[0,\pi]$ is enough to derive what you want.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a proof that does not use the notion of function, a "purely geometrical proof" so to speak.